# newbie questions about plesk and iis7

Tags: iis-7, plesk

i'm just trying to understand how plesk works on a win 2008 server, you can eg. create domains, subdomains via the plesk webpanel. 
i got several questions about it:

1. does plesk have an own dns server for hosting the dns entries when creating subdomains?
   is it possible to access those settings directly from the server (not the webpanel)?
2. what happens when i'm enabling the IIS dns server - will plesk stop working?
3. i want to run php on the IIS, so i installed it via the platform installer which said that mysql is already installed (i assume its from plesk) - how can i use my own mysql server for php?
4. does plesk make much sense at all? i mean all i need from it is for creating subdomains/dns entries, wouldn't it also be possible/easier by using IIS only?

thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the questions are for your hoster and not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. For Bind in config files, for MS DNS in MMC panel
2. Don't you confuse IIS dns server with Microsoft DNS server? MS DNS server is supported by Plesk and installed by Plesk by default. You can switch BIND to MS DNS in web panel.
3. You don't need to do anything to use MySQL for PHP. You just need to know host, database name, user name and password to use it inside PHP scripts or PHP applications. You can connect(register) any MySQL server in Plesk in "Tools & Settings"(if you are plesk admin)
4. Well, actually it depends of how often you will add/manage domains/subdomains/databases. If only couple in a week, than plesk doesn't make sense for you. Plesk target audience starts from "small" hosters and web studies with really big bunch of work. If you know how to setup all hosting stack manually and think that it not much of work than you don't need Plesk.